# Variable og:image in Tumblr text posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, tumblr

I've searched on StackOverflow and other sites, but I haven't found a definite yes or no answer if this is possible.

I'm getting the hang of Facebook's Open Graph technology and I want to have a variable image between posts on my Tumblr. The problem is, I typically only make text posts and Tumblr doesn't seem to allow me to specify Open Graph images for each post. Tumblr deletes the meta tag if I try to put it within the post and Facebook doesn't seem to recognize tumblr tags like {PhotoURL-500} or {Photoset-500} within the og:image tag.

My og:image is currently set to display the site's logo, which gets repetitive, but without it, Facebook typically doesn't scrape the right image. Is it possible to set the og:image for individual Tumblr text posts?

Comment: Some solutions to similar problems [here](http://eyedealab.com/add-facebook-likebutton-tumblr-posts-opengraph/)

Answer (score 0):

Text posts don't have any images registered in them that you could invoke with a themecode like `{PhotoURL}`. If the in-post meta tags are stripped out, I don't think there's another option.

You might be able to hack something together with a second `{block:Posts}` loop in the `<head>`, but that wouldn't work on permalink pages.